# Use SQL IN inside vb.net dataset adaptor

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset

I'm trying to use a dataset adapter in my asp.net/vb.net website. But I need to search using multiple values, Ideally, i'd just like to pass an in statement in to my dataset adapter. Is this possible, as how it is, it doesn't seem to bring back anything:

Heres my data adapter:

[image]

The query is:

```
select * from joblist where username in (@username)
```

I'm trying to call it with:

```
Private dtJobs As Barry.joblistDataTable
Private taJobs As New BarryTableAdapters.joblistTableAdapter

  dtJobs = New Barry.joblistDataTable
  dtJobs = taJobs.FilterSearch("'tomb','martinm','chrise'")

rptJobList.DataSource = dtJobs
rptJobList.DataBind()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in a comma separated string, a single parameter. You cannot use it as is in an `IN` statement.

You have to split it into table, for example using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/314917/961695). Using this function (I assume you're using SQL Server as your DB) you can rewrite your query as:

```
select joblist.* from joblist 
inner join dbo.Split(',', @username) t
on joblist.username = t.s
```

This approach splits your multi-value parameter into table and joins to the original table

Comment: dbo.Split() is the old solution. The new solution, if the technology stack supports it, is to use a table-value parameter.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes, depending on version of the SQL Server. Also for TVP you cannot pass a string, which is what OP seems to want

Comment: Invalid object name 'dbo.Split'. - Is there something wrong there?

Comment: @TomBeech did you create the function from the solution shown in the link?